# Can't install Microsoft.aspnet.mvc.taghelpers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I try to run

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers -Pre
```

I get the following error:

> Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers 6.0.0-beta8'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references 
>   or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: Nothing to do with Classic ASP. Please retag.

Comment: What frameworks have you specified in your project.json?